# Error while running the integration test

Tags: magento2.3.0, integration-test

I am trying to create a integration test to check if my module is enabled or not.

Following is the code in my test class

```
<?php

namespace Anshu\Learning\Test\Integration;

use Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
use Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleList;
use Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class LearningConfigTest extends TestCase
{
    private $moduleName = 'Anshu_Learning';

    public function testIsModuleConfiguredAndEnabled()
    {
        /**
         * @var ObjectManager $objectManager
         */
        $objectManager = new ObjectManager($this);

        /**
         * @var DirectoryList $dirList
         */
        $dirList = $objectManager->getObject(DirectoryList::class, ['root' => BP]);

        /**
         * @var DeploymentConfig\Reader $configReader
         */
        $configReader = $objectManager->getObject(DeploymentConfig\Reader::class, ['dirList' => $dirList]);

        /**
         * @var DeploymentConfig $deploymentConfig
         */
        $deploymentConfig = $objectManager->getObject(DeploymentConfig::class, ['reader' => $configReader]);

        /**
         * @var ModuleList $moduleList
         */
        $moduleList = $objectManager->getObject(ModuleList::class, ['config' => $deploymentConfig]);

        $this->assertTrue($moduleList->has($this->moduleName), 'Module is not enabled');
    }
}
```

While running the test I am getting error message `Use of undefined constant BP - assumed 'BP' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)`

And when I am changing `BP` to `DirectoryList::ROOT` then I am getting following error message

```
array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
 vendor/magento/framework/App/DeploymentConfig/Reader.php:113
 vendor/magento/framework/App/DeploymentConfig.php:140
 vendor/magento/framework/App/DeploymentConfig.php:70
 vendor/magento/framework/Module/ModuleList.php:143
 vendor/magento/framework/Module/ModuleList.php:114
 app/code/Anshu/Learning/Test/Integration/LearningConfigTest.php:49
```

PHP version is 7.2

May someone can help me to figure out and fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import this class `Magento\TestFramework\ObjectManager` instead of `Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager`.

Then initialize `ObjectManager` by this:

```
$objectManager = ObjectManager::getInstance();
```

Comment: I am getting Error : Class 'Magento\TestFramework\ObjectManager' not found

Comment: here is a complete explanation by Vinai Kopp https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JvBWJ6Lm9MU